# Entity Framework - Search in 3 tables efficiently

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

in my DB I have 3 tables like below :
 [image]

I also have an Autocomplete field in my page in which visitors can search by Country, Province or City and as you know after inserting 3 letter, the search should be conducted by each letter that is inserted. now it seems so costly searching through each table in turn and successively.
 I also know that City is the most searched field. so what should be the best approach for searching in my case? I should mention that I didn't deploy my web app yet and I can change tables and it's relations.

a code sample would be great.
thanks in advance 
MA

Comment: firstly your relations are wrong, all you have is 0 to 1 you could store all this in one table. As for efficient searching and autocomplete etc you should look at caching some data.

Comment: @Mark Homer about storing all in one table, can you explain more how can i distinguish between the cities of each country if i save theme in one table ??

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do two things

1. Create a flat(denormalized data) table combining all the three tables and do the searching in that. Also, you may have to create some triggers on this table to sync the flat table data with data of the actual table.
2. In a second way, you have to search each table conditionally. Like in your case city is most likely to search then,

   a. Search each table

   b. Transform the results into a common type

   c. Merge the results

   d. Sort/select from this merged list